# where is my presenting segue in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, segue

I got in trouble with disappearing issue of some attributes in presenting segues.

Ideally, presenting segues are supposed to include *"show", "show details", "present modally", and "present as popover"* however, I can't find those attributes in my project.

Check out this :

[image]

Another projects work well, and also include those attributes.

Does anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Your storyboard is probably set to opens in older Xcode version.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a segue. It's a relationship. (i.e.: between a container and a scene)  So it doesn't have the attributes you are looking for.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AboutStoryboards.html